# Is NSCollectionView compatible with CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-management, nscollectionview

Update:
This thread identifies a bug in NSCollectionView when the represented objects of the collection view are NSManagedObjects.  The bug is triggered as follows;

(a) Delete objects from the NSArrayController
(b) Perform save on the related nsmanagedobjectcontext any time after the deletion and before the NSCollectionView has finished its animation.

These projects on github demonstrate the issue.

https://github.com/artifacts/NSCollectionViewCoreDataBug
https://github.com/iracooke/CoreDataCollectionViewCrashing

### Original question below

I have an NSCollectionView setup with its content binding bound to arrangedObjects of an NSArrayController of core-data entities. In my Collection Item View (the prototype for the NSCollectionView view) I have several controls bound via representedObject of my collectionview item to my core-data entities.

For the most part this works OK.

I encounter an objc_exception when I try to delete entities from my ArrayController.  I delete these entities simply by calling;

```
[myArrayController removeObject:managedObjectToDelete];
```

Unfortunately, when I do this I frequently get a "CoreData could not fulfill a fault" Error .. with the responsible entity being one of the entities being managed by the NSArrayController.

Examination of the call-stack when the exception is thrown reveals that the crash originates when the NSCollectionView receives its _endOfAnimation method.  This in turn initiates other methods to do with unbinding (likely of properties of my entity with controls in my view).

One further bit of info is that the Entity I'm working with has no relationships to other entities in my model.

It looks to me as though the following problem is occurring;

- When I delete objects from my NSArrayController they are in turn deleted from the context.
- After deletion from the context the objects are turned into faults
- The NSCollectionView has retained references to the objects (now faults). It tries to clean them up at the end of its animation (unbinding etc).
- When NSCollectionView tries to cleanup bindings to the object it causes core data to attempt to fire a fault on the object (hope I got my terminology right there).  This causes an error because the object has not yet been saved to disk.

The only way I can think of to prevent this, is to persist the objects in the store (by saving them) prior to deletion.  This works, but only in a hackish kind of way since I need to ensure that one round of deletion is complete before saving again ... and since the error occurs during an animation .. after some delay .. and two saves in succession would result in the same error occuring again.

Does this mean that I cannot used a Core-Data backed NSArrayController to populate an NSCollectionView?  If not what am I doing wrong? Is there a better way around this issue?

Comment: I've set up another project demonstrating the problem and filed a bug, it's radar #9903150. You'll find the project and bug description here: https://github.com/artifacts/NSCollectionViewCoreDataBug

Comment: Thanks for that. Your github project is a nicer reproduction of the bug than mine. I guess Apple have a pretty good description of the problem now from this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct yet boring answer: I can confirm that a Core Data backed NSArrayController can populate an NSCollectionView, with different GUI objects in the collection NSView item bound to the generated "Collection View Item" and referring to various Core Data objects along the path. Programmatically deleting (and re-ordering) elements of the NSArrayController works (with animation for free).

Perhaps some bindings or other dependencies inside your Collection View are causing the problem? Or a threading issue with the Managed Object Context(s)?

Comment: Thanks. Are any of the GUI objects in your prototype view animated?  One of mine is a progress indicator.  From memory it was unbinding this object which caused the crash.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase my question to "Is NSCollectionView compatible with bindings and core-data".  Your answer "perhaps some bindings are causing the problem" is almost certainly correct ... but we should be able to use bindings. +1 for answering but it doesn't quite solve it for me.

Comment: My working NSCollectionViewItem code includes an indicator which is dynamic and frequently updated (30Hz) from a network source, with all connections done through bindings with Interface Builder. As far as i can try, i cannot get things to crash, regardless of the collection animation timing. Do you bind only through IB? What happens when you remove the binding to the progress indicator? (to be sure that it is really the cause of the problem). At this point some trimmed code reproducing your issue would help identify exactly what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for that follow-up.  I built a minimal project last night and demonstrated to myself that it does work perfectly as you say.  I can't reproduce my bug yet but I'm accepting this answer because there must be something else in my code causing the problem. When I discover what it is I'll post back here for posterity.

Comment: I found the cause. Apparently it is not possible to make this work if you also retain the managed objects elsewhere in your code. I've uploaded a mini project to github demonstrating the problem. (See edits to original question).

Comment: i think the problem is because you save the Managed Object Context while the animation is performed (removing your save message removes the error). Removing an object from the NSArrayController causes it to be removed from the Core Data object graph and marked for deletion, but not actually deleted. Deletion of the object is performed upon save. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-SW4

Comment: Aha .. yes thank you.  I have update the project to make it much more minimal.  The issue is still a bug I think because it's very difficult to ensure that save is not performed on a managedobjectcontext while animation is occurring. Even if I perform the save with performSelector:afterDelay I still get a crash.

Comment: i agree that NSCollectionView could be more collaborative with notifications but we're starting to drift away from the "question"... the crash is not due to the Core Data fault error (which itself is harmless) but to the next NSArrayController item deletion process. You could examine NSManagedObjectContext deletedObjects in the save: and check their retainCount and figure from there if it's still held in the NSCollectionView before actually doing the save (and disable the clear button for the time of the delete/save process).

Comment: I dunno .. doesn't that seem like a bug to you? I should be able to use the core-data API's like delete and save without thinking about when the NSCollectionView is going to finish its animation?  In the call stack for the crash, it originates in the NSCOllectionView method for ending the animation.  Seems like NSCollectionView should not be doing its unbinding at the end of the animation, but should do it at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent this problem by adding a (assign) property to your CollectionItem which  points to the corresponding ArrayController.

This property can be set in -[YourNSCollectionViewSubClass newItemWithRepresentedObject:].

Then you can observe arrangedObjects in each item.
When it changes and item.representedObject is not contained in arrangedObjects any more,
you set item.representedObject to nil. In my testing (10.6.8), this triggers the binding cleanup before CoreData turns the objects into faults.
(My objects have relationships and the item view has bindings into them).

btw: This problem is not restricted to saving during animation,
undo/redo/save combinations can trigger it too.

I was looking for a good place to start the observation inside the item but
the only one I came up with was copyWithZone: which I wanted to avoid.
(-awakeFromNib is called only for the first item, -view is too early).

Therefore I (reluctantly) decided to start the observation in -newItemWithRepresentedObject:
and stop it in the item's -dealloc.

You should also watch out for any controls or other actions triggered by objects
in the item view - by rapid clicking I could cause messages to deallocated objects,
presumably because the still reacting buttons where animating away under the mouse.
My solution is to disable the controls when setting representedObject to nil. YMMV.

Here is my observer code:

```
    - (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if( object == self.arrayController && [keyPath isEqualToString: @"arrangedObjects"] ) {
        if( NO == [self.arrayController.arrangedObjects containsObject: self.representedObject] ) {
            self.representedObject = nil;

            for(NSView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
                if( [subview isKindOfClass: [NSControl class]] ) {
                    [(NSControl *)subview setEnabled: NO];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject: object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, and thanks for sharing it.  In my view though, it's pretty clear that NSCollectionView is broken with core-data, if we need to go to such lengths to prevent it from crashing.  I'm thinking I should file a bug report to Apple on this topic.